# Singular method name for single object argument, plural for a list?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having a problem with naming a method for a database application.

In my `Database` instance, I have a method that can remove an `Agreement` object from the database. However, I want to be able to remove multiple `Agreement`s at once, to be able to use transactions. The problem is that I also have an overload to remove a single `Agreement` object.

Essentially, my structure is like this:

```
public class Database
{
    // ...

    public void RemoveAgreement(Agreement a)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void RemoveAgreement(IEnumerable<Agreement> agreements)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But this can be confusing, as the overload with the list of `Agreement`s has a singular name, despite being inherently plural.

My question is, **how should I structure this? Should I have two overloads with the name `RemoveAgreement()`, or `RemoveAgreements()`? Or should I use two separate methods, instead of overloads?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say that for the method that receives the list as parameter the name `RemoveAgreement` is not correct for the reason you describe.

I would call it `RemoveAgreements`

For the name of your class (Database) I would say that you're using it as DAO for ALL your entities.

If you were using this class ONLY for Agreement entities I would have this 2 methods

`public void Remove(Agreement agreement)`

and

`public void Remove(IEnumerable<Agreement> agreements)`

Comment: Yeah, it's a fairly small application, it just tracks three types of objects, so I figured it would be less complicated to just use a single DAO.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do in that situation:

```
public void RemoveAgreement (Agreement agreement)
{
    // Do Stuff
}

public void RemoveAgreements (IEnumerable<Agreement> agreements)
{
    foreach (Agreement a in agreements)
    {
        RemoveAgreement(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using separate names, and making an overload of the plural version that takes a `params Agreement[]`.